# Redirect Tablet, Mobile, Desktop

Tags: javascript, redirect, user-agent

My problem is not understanding `User Agent Strings`  and how to put most complete if I can, listing all mobile User Agent, and transfer them to `HTTP://127.0.0.11/M/` and all Tablet User Agent to `HTTP://127.0.0.1/T/` .

I have successfully done it by using this old script I got on website, but I don't know how to put more complete sets, and transfer them to Tablet folder. IpadPro in Google Chrome only transfers to M, and not T folder.

```
if (/iP(hone|od)|android.+mobile|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1/M/");
} else if (/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1/T/");
}
```

Here are some of the tablets strings, and I'm figuring out how to put multiple strings to a javascript code.

User Agent Strings of tablets :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/30.0.1599.12 Mobile/11A465 Safari/8536.25 (3B92C18B-D9DE-4CB7-A02A-22FD2AF17C8F)
browser: Safari 7   operating system: iOS 7 primarily used on: tablet
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
browser: Safari 7   operating system: iOS 7 primarily used on: tablet
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
```

Comment: Amit Verma, thank you so much Amit Verma for your kindness for editing my question, and making it better, I don't know how to follow you here, but I am grateful. I'm a Filipino-Indian seeking help, thank you so much. @Amit Verma

Comment: Thanks Dharman, for editing it again.